# UWP: The process has no package identity

Tags: uwp

I am studying UWP-FullTrust project, which demonstrate how to use UWP with Desktop Extension. The code is in below link:

https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust.git

https://github.com/StefanWickDev/UWP-FullTrust/tree/master/UWP_FullTrust_3

And for the UWP_FullTrust_3 part, below codes, the last line causes runtime error.

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeAppServiceConnection();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Open connection to UWP app service
        /// </summary>
        private async void InitializeAppServiceConnection()
        {
            connection = new AppServiceConnection();
            connection.AppServiceName = "SampleInteropService";
            connection.PackageFamilyName = Package.Current.Id.FamilyName;
```

The error is below. Why and how to solve it?

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in FullTrust.exe
>   An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   FullTrust.exe but was not handled in user code The process has no
>   package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP: The process has no package identity

For my testing, I reproduce your issue with run `FullTrust` project separately, For this solution you need run `Package` desktop bridge that referred `FullTrust` and `UWP`project. If the `FullTrust` run in the untrust process when run without [`LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher), it could not get `FamilyName`.